# Duvida template "maven-archetype-webapp"

Tags: java, maven

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento com Maven e estou tendo algumas duvidas. Seguinte, gostaria de criar uma aplicação Java web, para isso comecei rodando o seguinte comando:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.myapp -DartifactId=CounterWebApp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

A seguir a seguinte estrutura de diretório foi construída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha duvida: Porque o Maven não criou um diretório para os .java, no meu caso vou usar servelets ,aonde eu as colocaria?, qual diretório?. É necessário cria-los manualmente?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu também gostaria de saber por que é que não cria.

Aliás, eu gostaria apenas que criasse mesmo (nem precisaria me contar por que nunca criou hehehe).

Mas o fato é que não cria e você terá que criar manualmente o diretório `java` abaixo de `src/main`, ou seja:

```
    CounterWebApp/
                src/
                    main/
                        java/
```

Abaixo de `src/main/java` que você pode criar os seus *packages* e, dentro dos packages, suas classes Java, inclusive os *servlets*, que serão reconhecidos e inicializados devido à anotação que você precisará usar para declará-los (`@WebServlet`).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!